Division ciphertext in SEAL BFV
I am building a Logistic Regression model over encrypted data. Based on my references. I need to scale like that to apply the approximate sigmoid function in the BFV scheme 
However, I don't know how to scale down results after that due to not having division operator. I tried to divide by p by multiplying with p^-1 and p^-1 in plaintext modulus, but with p^-1 the result is always 0, and in the other case, the result is too large. If anyone knows how to solve it, please help me :'(

If I have an encryption of a message m modulo t
, How can I obtain an encryption of round(m/p)?

Secure logistic regression was a task at the 2017 iDash competition. It looks like you have a quote from this paper. For competitions like iDash, (sometimes) participants make their code public. The winner was a team that included Miran Kim, who has public code here.

That being said, in that paper, how scaling is implemented is discussed right before section 3. In particular, they scale down as part of bootstrapping. So, things are highly unlikely to be as simple multiplying by the correct value.

Also, if you solely want to homomorphically compute the degree 3 polynomial $\sigma_3$, it might be easiest to work with methods to homomorphically compute polynomials. Here is some sample code using the OpenFHE library.

@MarkSchultz-Wu I have referred to the paper you mentioned above, as well as the papers that the author referenced and cited, in order to build a logistic regression (LR) model using the BFV scheme in the SEAL library (as mentioned in the paper). However, since there is no open-source code to refer to, I am facing many difficulties in constructing the FHE.bscale() function as described by the author. Most of the libraries I researched do not implement bootstrapping for BFV, and some do for CKKS. The library we are using, SEAL, does not implement either.

Due to the project requirements, I can only use BFV instead of other schemes. If you know anything related to constructing the bscale function, please let me know.

OpenFHE currently claims to currently have a prototype version of BFV bootstrapping available (see footnote 2 of this). The function $\mathsf{bscale}$ seems to require bootstrapping, so I would either look into using OpenFHE, or into implementing BFV bootstrapping in Seal yourself. Here is a recent paper implementing it, which includes a Magma implementation here, which might be a useful reference.

Thank you very much, I will refer to them.
